Is there any api or opensource tool to list out active running services in AWS?
I'm try to find out if there is any tool/api to list current running services in AWS account.
I tried cost explorer and billing dash board there it'll show deleted services as well. However in my case i want only current active services.
Tried AWS Trusted Advisor too, but it offers service limits and only covers certain services and doesn't support a complete list.

AWS Nuke can list all resources.
It is a utility written to delete resources, but by default it only lists resources. Best to run it with 'read-only' credentials to avoid anything bad happening!

I just want to list active services. E.g: if there is a Bucket in S3, then i need that s3 not the bucket names and all.

The AWS Resource Explorer could be used.

Resource Explorer allows you to find and view information about AWS resources in your account and from other accounts.

You could leverage the built-in search capability and export your resources to a CSV file to act upon them as you like.
